# Google Maps Distance Matrix API で住所間の移動時間を算出可能か？

Tags: google-maps

住所間の通勤時間(公共交通機関)と住所の最寄り駅を算出するAPIを探しています。

下記２点確認させてください。

(1) 「Google Maps Distance Matrix API」で、「住所間の移動時間」と「住所の最寄り駅」を算出する事は可能でしょうか。

(2) 上記(1)が可能な場合、
「Google Maps Distance Matrix API」を利用する事になると思いますが、
該当APIを利用した場合の移動時間と、
Googleで「移動時間 千葉県船橋市西習志野1丁目 静岡県沼津」と検索した場合の移動時間(公共交通機関タブを選択)と最寄り駅は、同じ結果になりますでしょうか。
「Google Maps Distance Matrix API」でどのような検索結果が得られるのかを確認したいです。

Answer (score 0):

おおよそドキュメントに載っているので、まずドキュメントを読むことをお勧めします: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix

Distance Matrix API は出発地点から到着地点まで特定の方法を使って移動したときの移動時間と移動距離を計算して返してくれる API です。このため移動時間は得ることができます。

一方で最寄り駅は難しいです。そもそも「最寄り駅」をどう定義するかという問題がありますし、Distance Matrix API はルート情報を返しません（https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview で書かれているようにルート情報が欲しい場合は Directions API を使います）。最寄り駅を知りたい住所を出発地点にし、周辺の駅すべてを到着地点にすることで移動時間が最も短い駅を導出することはできますが、コストが見合わない場合が多いかと思います。

そして、これらの結果が Google Maps で経路検索したときの結果と一致することは全く保証されていません。というより、リクエストとレスポンスの形式が違うので何をもって一致とするかから微妙です。そもそも何故一致することを確かめないといけないのか、から考え直すと良さそうです。

最後に、Distance Matrix API は特に高価な API という訳でもなく、ご自身で数回叩いてみる程度なら容易に行える価格設定です: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing。まずは適当なデータでリクエストしてみて挙動を確かめるのが理解の早道と思います。また、どうしても自分で実行しづらいということであれば、リクエストとレスポンスの具体例が https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/distance-matrix#distance-matrix-responses に載っています。